# Java client/server sockets

Tags: java, sockets, client, serversocket

I'm starting off with java sockets and have strange [lack of] output. Here's my source for the socket methods:

Client source code:

```
public void loginToServer(String host, String usnm ) {
    try {
        Socket testClient = new Socket(host,1042);
        System.out.println ("Connected to host at " + host);
        logString = ("CONNECTED: " + host);
        outGoing = new PrintWriter(testClient.getOutputStream(), true);
        outGoing.print("Hello from " + testClient.getLocalSocketAddress());
        InputStream inFromServer = testClient.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
        System.out.println("Server says " + in.readLine());
        testClient.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println ("Error connecting to host at " + host + ":1042.\n Reason: " + e);
        logString = ("CONNECT FAILED: " + host + ":1042: " + e);
    }
    printLog(logString);
    // send server usnm and os.name [System.getProperty(os.name)] ?
}
```

And the server code:

```
public void runServer() {
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(1042); 
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            printLog("LISTEN FAIL on 1042: " + e);
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port 1042.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        try{
            client = server.accept();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            printLog("ACCEPT FAIL on 1042: " + e);
            System.err.println("Accept failed: 1042");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        try{
            inComing = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            outGoing = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            printLog("READ FAIL on 1042: " + e);
            System.err.println("Read failed");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        while(true){
            try{
                clientData = inComing.readLine();
                //processingUnit(clientData, client);
                outGoing.print("Thank you for connecting to " + server.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            printLog("READ FAIL on 1042: " + e);
                System.out.println("Read failed");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the output the client gave was merely `Connected to host at localhost`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading lines but you aren't sending lines. Change `print()` to `println()`. `readLine()` will block forever waiting for the newline. It will return null at end of stream, i.e. when the peer closes the connection, but you aren't checking for that either, so you are looping indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing text and reading binary.  Since your output and input don't match its highly likely to hang in this case.

I suggest you either use binary with writeUTF/readUTF or text with println/readLine.

BTW: readUTF reads two bytes to determine the length of data to read. Since the first two bytes are ASCII text, you are likely to wait for around 16,000 characters before returning.

Comment: Thanks a bundle, I would never have guessed that. What situations does each type lend themselves to?

Comment: Text is good for sending human readable words and numbers. Binary is good for sending data efficiently and precisely.

Comment: that doesn't actually seem to be the problem. Having rectified this, it seems the server is not executing the code in the while loop? It is entering the loop, but not trying or catching...

Comment: The client and server are both waiting for the other to send some text. I would remove the DataInputStream as it is more likely to confuse than help.

Comment: why does the client not send text to the server before it waits for text?